# Changing category template for Joomshopping

Tags: joomla

I'm using joomla 2.5 with the joomshopping component. So I need a feature to change the template for different categories. I noticed that when I edit a category in the details tab joomshopping has a option to change category template. Now how can I do this, how can I change the template, where to install another template?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Path Template of joomshopping
root/component/com_joomshoping/template/
You can create  folder template here the same folder default